# AC Current and how it's connected

Tags: electric-circuits

Hi all just trying to get my head around this seriously confusing matter!

So Is AC basically like a battery but instead of chemical EMF you have magnetic EMF and does the current flow back to the 'negative' terminal of the generator or does it just disappear into the ground as the neutral side is connected to the earth.

Answer (score 0):

For DC and AC circuits you will always have exactly the same current exiting one terminal and entering the other terminal of the generator (battery). For AC the current direction is changing from positive to negative during each cycle. There is no current "disappearing" in the ground even if some current returns over the "ground"